# Tool to compare two different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to compare structure of approx. 50 tables in SQL Server 2005, and write T-Sql script to make them equal. Each table has its copy in the same database, the only difference being the name and structure (e.g. original "tableName" has to be compared to "tableName_copy", and the "tableName_copy" has missing constraints, PK, FK, triggers, etc).

I know there are lots of tools on the market (both free and commercial) to compare and prepare SQL scripts, but their problem is that they can compare tables with identical names in two databases, not giving option to choose which tables compare, even less if their names differ.

I was wondering if such tools exist (it would be great if they were free or open-source) to do this job of automating script generation for chosen tables of different names. I'd appreciate if anyone who has done similar job before share his/her experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you take a different approach, copying your `tablename_copy`s into a second database, but renaming them to `tablename`, and then running your favorite comparison tool?

Comment: Thanks Dan, this is actually a good idea. But after generating a comparison script and updating the "_copy" table, I need to move that table with data into the old database (dropping the original table, as the "_copy" one holds desired data). Any idea of how this could be accomplished? Those will be repetitive tasks (executed once a month), so "by script" solutions would be better than manual ones :)

Comment: Interesting. Will the schema ever differ, or is it only the data that needs comparing? And are you making decisions about the comparison, or are there just automatable rules?

Comment: Well, the story is much longer. There is a large database, with 1600+ tables, 600+ SP and lots of other objects (jobs, triggers and what not), used by several applications. There was a need to "strip" one of the apps, leaving only DB objects and schema used by this particular app. It was relatively easy to analyze this app and determine which DB objects it uses, but the problem appeared with cleaning data from the remaining 200+ tables (50+ tables have 12MM+ records each). The fastest way we found was `select into tableCopy` approach. The other option we're considering is to use ETL.

Comment: To clarify: `select into tableCopy` does not create full table structure (only a table with columns). No constraints, triggers, etc.

Comment: I see. It seems like most of that would be straightforward to automate, with the possible exception of the data cleanup. Perhaps one of the comparison tools will be able to generate a script for that part, though I don't have that level of experience with any of them. Hopefully someone else can chime in there.